# Unable to Bind TabControl to ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol

I search other similar question and I am still unable to bind my collection to the TabControl.
I managed to programmatically add headers and content.  But, I would like to use DataBinding

I defined a Struct with properties. I insert it in a public ObservableCollection and I tried to bind the collection to the TabControl.

Here is the c# code for the struct

```
   public struct ProbDiffList
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="ProbDiffList"/> struct.
    /// Construit une structure avec un identifiant de niveau et une liste de Problème à résoudre.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="diff">Niveau de difficulté.</param>
    /// <param name="lstProbleme">List de nom de Problème.</param>
    public ProbDiffList(string diff, List<string> lstProbleme)
    {
        NiveauProb = diff;
        LstProbName = lstProbleme;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets l'identification du niveau.
    /// </summary>
    public string NiveauProb { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets la liste des problèmes.
    /// </summary>
    public List<string> LstProbName { get; private set; }
}
```

Here is the XAML

```
           <TabControl x:Name="GamesList"
                    Margin="10"
                    Padding="10"
            DataContext="probClasser">

            <TabItem Header="{Binding probClasser/NiveauProb}"
                         FontWeight="Bold"
                         FontSize="14" >
                <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding probClasser/LstProbName}"></ListBox>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
```

and the c# part

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Liste des problème pour BINDING avec les titres.
    /// </summary>
    public static ObservableCollection<ProbDiffList> probClasser;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = probClasser;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Affichera la liste des Sudokus à résoudre classé par catégorie.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="argProb">List niveau List infoProb.</param>
    public void AfficheChoixProblème(List<ProbDiffList> argProb)
    {
        probClasser = new ObservableCollection<ProbDiffList>();
        GamesList.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        foreach (ProbDiffList uneListeParDiff in argProb)
        {
            probClasser.Add(uneListeParDiff);
        }
    }
```

This should display
[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwWHV.png)

Comment: 1. The DataContext seems wrong. Try to remove it.
2. probClasser is a field, you can bind only to properties.
3. And why is probClasser  static?

Answer (score 0):

You should bind the ItemsSource of the TabControl and instead of explicitly creating TabItems, set the ItemTemplate and ContentTemplate:

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding NiveauProb}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding LstProbName}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

Comment: Thank you it work when I use ItemTemplate and remove the DataContext as suggested by @KlausGutter

Comment: Sure, instead of setting the DataContext (to a string) in XAML, just bind the ItemsSource - to the DataContext set in code behind.